# Celery worker hangs on ZEO database access (race condition?)

Tags: python, database, django, celery, zodb

### Problem

Celery workers are hanging on task execution when using a package which accesses a ZEO server. However, if I were to access the server directly within `tasks.py`, there's no problem at all.

#### Background

I have a program that reads and writes to a [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/) file. Because I want multiple users to be able to access and modify this database concurrently, I have it managed by a [ZEO server](http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/zeo.html), which *should* make it safe across multiple processes and threads. I define the database within a module of my program:

```
from ZEO import ClientStorage
from ZODB.DB import DB

addr = 'localhost', 8090
storage = ClientStorage.ClientStorage(addr, wait=False)
db = DB(storage)
```

### SSCCE

I'm obviously attempting more complex operations, but let's assume I only want the keys of a root object, or its children. I can produce the problem in this context.

I create `dummy_package` with the above code in a module, `databases.py`, and a bare-bones module meant to perform database access:

```
# main.py

def get_keys(dict_like):
    return dict_like.keys()
```

---

If I don't try any database access with `dummy_package`, I can import the database and access root without issue:

```
# tasks.py
from dummy_package import databases

@task()
def simple_task():

    connection = databases.db.open()
    keys = connection.root().keys()
    connection.close(); databases.db.close()
    return keys  # Works perfectly
```

However, trying to pass a connection or a child of `root` makes the task hang indefinitely.

```
@task()
def simple_task():
    connection = databases.db.open()
    root = connection.root()
    ret = main.get_keys(root)  # Hangs indefinitely
    ...
```

If it makes any difference, these Celery tasks are accessed by Django.

## Question

So, first of all, what's going on here? Is there some sort of race condition caused by accessing the ZEO server in this way?

I *could* make all database access Celery's responsibility, but that will make for ugly code. Furthermore, it would ruin my program's ability to function as a standalone program. Is it not possible to interact with ZEO within a routine called by a Celery worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what's going on, but I'm thinking the deadlock has something to do with the fact that Celery uses [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) by default for concurrency. Switching over to using Eventlet for tasks that need to access the ZEO server solved my problem.

#### My process

1. Start up a worker that [uses Eventlet](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet), and one that uses standard `multiproccesing`.

   `celery` is the name of the default queue ([for historical reasons](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing)), so have the Eventlet worker handle this queue:

   ```
   $ celery worker --concurrency=500 --pool=eventlet --loglevel=debug \ 
                    -Q celery                --hostname eventlet_worker
   $ celery worker  --loglevel=debug \
                    -Q multiprocessing_queue --hostname multiprocessing_worker
   ```
2. [Route tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) which need standard `multiprocessing` to the appropriate queue. All others will be routed to the `celery` queue (Eventlet-managed) by default. (If using Django, this goes in `settings.py`):

   ```
   CELERY_ROUTES = {'project.tasks.ex_task': {'queue': 'multiprocessing_queue'}}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Do not save an open connection or its root object as a global.

You need a connection per-thread; just because ZEO makes it possible for multiple threads to access, it sounds like you are using something that is not thread-local (e.g. module-level global in databases.py).

Save the db as a global, but call db.open() during each task.  See http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#connection-pool

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I read the docs, and now only define the db in a module. However, I'm still having the hanging problem, whether I open a connection within the context of `tasks.py`, or directly within my program code. I updated my question - is there any chance you might be able to share any insight?

Comment: Hard to say; maybe add logging to your task method to figure out where things hang?

Comment: I've done that. Specifically, things hang at the very first attempt to access the database (within my program, that is). I can log messages all the way up until an access statement, then it hangs. I'm thinking it might be a [multiprocessing issue](http://www.dctrwatson.com/2010/09/python-thread-safe-does-not-mean-fork-safe/), but still trying to figure it out.